# java.io.NotSerializableException - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection

Tags: java, serialization, jdbc, ojdbc

I am trying to add data to a Oracle Database table. Even though the data gets added, the page does not refresh but shows the following error: **java.io.NotSerializableException - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection**

Here's my java code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean(name="adder")
@ViewScoped
public class Add implements Serializable {

    private String pno;
    private String pfname;
    private String psname;
    private String city;
    private String ppsno;
    private String insurance;
    private String contact;
    private String mhistory;

    private Connection con;

    public String getPno() {
        return pno;
    }
    public void setPno(String pno) {
        this.pno = pno;
    }
    public String getPfname() {
        return pfname;
    }
    public void setPfname(String pfname) {
        this.pfname = pfname;
    }
    public String getPsname() {
        return psname;
    }
    public void setPsname(String psname) {
        this.psname = psname;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getPpsno() {
        return ppsno;
    }
    public void setPpsno(String ppsno) {
        this.ppsno = ppsno;
    }
    public String getInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }
    public void setInsurance(String insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance;
    }
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
    public String getMhistory() {
        return mhistory;
    }
    public void setMhistory(String mhistory) {
        this.mhistory = mhistory;
    }

private Connection getConnection(){

        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String usr = "scott";
        String pass = "Silver90$";

        Connection cnn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);

            cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cnn;
    }


public void AddAction() throws SQLException
{
    this.con=this.getConnection();
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String sql = "insert into PATIENT1 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);


    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, pno);
    pst.setString(2, pfname);
    pst.setString(3, psname);
    pst.setString(4, city);
    pst.setString(5, ppsno);
    pst.setString(6, insurance);
    pst.setString(7, contact);
    pst.setString(8, mhistory);


    pst.executeUpdate();

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Patient added successfully.", "Patient Info generated Successfully!");

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }





}
```

Here's my .xhtml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:body>

<h1 align="center"> Add the Patient's Details over here:</h1>

<h:form>
 <h:outputLabel>Patient No: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="pno" value="#{adder.pno}" size="20" required="true" 
 label ="Pno"> 
 </h:inputText>
 <h:message for="pno" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>

 <h:outputLabel>First Name: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="pfname" value="#{adder.pfname}" size="20" required="false" 
 label ="Pfname">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="pfname" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>

 <h:outputLabel>Last Name: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="psname" value="#{adder.psname}" size="20" required="true" 
 label ="Psname">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="psname" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>



 <h:outputLabel>City: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="city" value="#{adder.city}" size="20" required="true" 
 label ="City">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="city" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>


 <h:outputLabel>PPS No.: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="ppsno" value="#{adder.ppsno}" size="20" required="true" 
 label ="Ppsno">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="ppsno" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>

 <h:outputLabel>Insurance: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="insurance" value="#{adder.insurance}" size="20" required="false" 
 label ="Insurance">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="insurance" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>


 <h:outputLabel>Contact: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="contact" value="#{adder.contact}" size="20" required="true" 
 label ="Contact">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="contact" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>






 <h:outputLabel>Medical History: </h:outputLabel>
 <h:inputText id="mhistory" value="#{adder.mhistory}" size="20" required="false" 
 label ="Mhistory">
 </h:inputText> 
 <h:message for="mhistory" style="color:red"/>
 <br/>
 <br/>


 <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{adder.AddAction}"/>

 <br></br>          
 <h:commandButton value="Reception Home Page" action="reception2"/>

 <br></br>          
 <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="login2"/>


 </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jny  Surprisingly, this worked when I changed **@ViewScoped** to **@SessionScoped**. But. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that underlying code is trying to serialize Add object. But because one of the properties (Connection) is not Serializable, it throws an exception. One of the ways is to declare Connection as transient. But I would advise to refactor the code and take jdbc related logic out of the class

Comment: Even after shifting the code out of the class, it did not work. The problem is that my data is getting added to the Table, but I am still getting the error in my stack: **javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection**. Thanks for your help.